# Return rows for IN query with failed look-ups returning NULL

Tags: sql, vectorwise

**Given this query:**

```
SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a IN ('v1', 'v2', 'v3');
```

If table `c` had values for v1 and v2 but not v3, I'd get a result set of 2 rows.  Is there a way I can perform the same query (or one that yields the same outcome) while getting a row for every target?

In this case, I'd like to receive 3 rows, 2 with the values for 'v1' and 'v2' and one with a NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will work on your particular RDBMS, but here's how I would approach it:

```
select x.a, c.b
from (
  select 'v1' as a union all
  select 'v2' as a union all
  select 'v3' as a
) x
left outer join c on c.a = x.a
```

Create a temporary table and use it to left-join in your desired table.

Comment: Why not nvl(a,'N\A') IN ('v1', ... ,'N\A')  ?